# Parent class methods bein called despise declaration on subclass

Tags: python

I've already looked into this link: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/new-new-method.html

But even tough I followed these instructions there's something bothering me on my code:

error_manager.py:

```
class error_manager:
    def __new__(cls):
        cls._error = 0
        cls._er_string = "None"
        return cls
```

database.py:

```
from error_manager import error_manager as EM

class Database(EM):
    def __new__(cls, table_name="", database_name=""):
        inst = EM.__new__(cls) #THIS LINE
        return inst

    def __init__(self, table_name="", database_name=""):
        print("init dtb")
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.database_name = database_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.table_name + " " + self.database_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.table_name + " " + self.database_name
```

run:

```
dtb = Database("tbl", "dtb")
print(dtb)
```

This outputs:

```
<class '__main__.Database'>
```

Why it's not calling either __str_ or __repr_ methods from the subclass?

Plus on the line #THIS LINE it says "Too many arguments positional arguments for method call. But if I remove the arguments the script won't run. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the class itself from `errormanger.__new__`, not an instance of that class. `__new__` should look something like

```
class error_manager:
    def __new__(cls):
        inst = object.__new__(cls)
        inst._error = 0
        inst._er_string = "None"
        return inst
```

As is, though, it would be simpler to override `__init__` instead of `__new__`, unless there is other work not shown that requires `__new__` to be overridden.

```
class error_manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self._error = 0
        self._er_string = "None"
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the first solution saying that Database is not a subtype of type, should it be something else?
The second solution worked just fine.

Comment: My fault; that should be `object.__new__`, not `type.__new__`.